# VTCompressionSessionCreate is always crash

Tags: video-toolbox

This is crash when i want to create a VTCompressionSessionRef by use VTCompressionSessionCreate, who can tell me why?????

```
 dispatch_sync(aQueue, ^{

        // Create the compression session
        OSStatus status = VTCompressionSessionCreate(NULL, width, height, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, NULL, NULL, NULL, didCompressH264, (__bridge void *)(self),  &EncodingSession);
        NSLog(@"H264: VTCompressionSessionCreate %d", (int)status);

        if (status != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"H264: Unable to create a H264 session");
            error = @"H264: Unable to create a H264 session";

            return ;

        }
}
```

status is always -12912 when it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

According to VideoToolbox/VTErrors.h:

```
kVTVideoEncoderMalfunctionErr           = -12912,
```

Could your hardware encoder be malfunctioning?